# how to get confirmation box value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

condition :

when i submit a button, the system will check database A and run query data using mysql. if any data exist, a popup box will ask if i want to proceed with the action, if i answer ok, the system will check database B and run query and ask the same question. if i answer ok, the system will update the database. can i use javascript in php for this situation?

my current script

```
if($_POST['submit']){
    $check = $db->check_table($idnumber);
    if($check>1){ echo "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('Proceed?')</script>"; }
}
```

how do i get the value of the confirmation box when i click ok or cancel so that i can proceed to check the second table.

Comment: Embedding one language in another is usually a bad idea. Consider splitting your single call up into two: verifying the action, and then executing the action.

Comment: You can try using JQuery Ajax

Comment: care to give an example? @EngCy

Answer (score 0):

I would just enclose your HTML in an if statement in PHP

```
<?
if($_POST['submit']){
$check = $db->check_table($idnumber);
    if($check>1){?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>$(function() {confirm('Proceed?')});</script>
    <?
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: how do i check if the value i click ok or cancel?